# Converting sqlite result to std::string in C++

Tags: c++, sql, casting, sqlite

Im querying a sqlite db, but i need to convert the result (a TEXT attribute) to a C++ std::string. I feel like this should not be hard to accomplish, but im having trouble.

```
sqlite3_open("sqlite.db", &db);
std::string str = "SELECT something FROM table";
sqlite3_prepare_v2(db,
str.c_str(),
-1,
&m_statement,
0);

sqlite3_step(m_statement);
// OBS: 3rd party printf, cannot use std::cout in this environment
printf("Result1: %s",sqlite3_column_text(m_statement,0)); // OK! Result is printed

string try1 = string(
    reinterpret_cast<const char*>(sqlite3_column_text(m_statement,0))); 
printf("Result2: %s",try1); // null

stringstream ss;
ss << sqlite3_column_text(m_statement,0);
printf("Result3: %s",ss.str()); // null
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem isn't related to sqlite. When you use `%s` with `printf`, `printf` expects a `char *` NOT a `std::string`.

For example change this:

```
 printf("Result2: %s",try1); // null
```

to

```
 printf("Result2: %s",try1.c_str());
```

and see what happens.

C++ has two primary ways of implementing strings. The legacy C string (`char*`) and the `std::string` class found in the C++ standard library. If you deal with C APIs, you'll be dealing mostly with the former. `printf` and `sqlite*` are both from C APIs, so expect to deal with `char*`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not with `sqlite3_column_text`.

`printf` format specifier `%s` expects a C string (char pointer).

As `printf` can't inspect what values are passed on the stack, so it has to trust the format specifier. Because the format specifier is `%s`, it reads an argument as it was a char pointer (it's not), but by coincidence, it's printing the wrong result, rather than crashing.

`std::string` exposes a function that gets you a read-only corresponding C string, so, for example, your the second case will be:

```
// Get a C string from std::string
printf("Result2: %s", try1.c_str());
```